# how to make a Jbutton as rectangle

Tags: java, swing

I have a `sortableTableModel`. On click of column headers I sort the content. For sorting, column headers are treated as `jbutton`.

Now my `jbutton` are created with **rounded corners** so in my table column headers have [rounded corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpHP5.png).

I want those as **plane rectangles**.

how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this -

```
TableColumn col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(vColIndex);
col.setHeaderRenderer(new CustomTableHeaderRenderer());
```

And then create your own TableCellRenderer that extends whatever JComponent you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look in to [TableCellRenderers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) and [TableColumn.setHeaderRenderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html#setHeaderRenderer%28javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer%29)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the border/do some custom painting modifications to the buttons you are using in the table header.

Answer (score 1):

if is your Java version 1.6 ++, than why not using default `TableHeader` that's came with `JTable` (by defalut returns `JLabel`) and with defalut `RowSorter` http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting ,

but another situations could be if is implemented in your `sortableTableModel` custom `RowFilter`